# La animación de Sweetalert2 no se completa correctamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert2

Tengo un problema, cuando el sweetalert se muestra, no finaliza la animación, sino que queda estancado en la posición de la imagen adjuntada. He intentado desactivando la animación con `animation:false;`, pero no se desactiva la animación, sino que sigue realizando el mismo comportamiento.

Mi código JS es el siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Manejar el evento clic del botón "Enviar"
    document.getElementById("enviarButton").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtener los datos del formulario
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("videoForm"));

        // Realizar la solicitud AJAX
        fetch("./cargarvideos.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Éxito',
                    text: data.message,
                    animation: false
                  });                  
                // Limpiar el formulario o redirigir a otra página si es necesario
                document.getElementById("videoForm").reset();
            } else {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: data.message,
                    animation: true
                  });
                  
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            Swal.fire("Error", "Error en la solicitud AJAX", "error");
        });
    });
});
```

Cabe destacar que la versión que estoy utilizando es la 11.7.31 de Sweetalert2.

```
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.31/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: limpia el cache XD

Answer (score 0):

*Hola intenta con este CDN en tu codigo*

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.31/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.31/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

*esto me ha funcionado a mi, espero que lo haga contigo*